# convertApi not including fonts in html jpg conversion

Tags: convertapi

I am using [convertapi](https://www.convertapi.com) in order to generate an image from a html page (web 2 jpg) and it is not including the fonts that i am loading from a css file.

Have unsuccessfully tried to include this fonts in the file head.

this is the way im loading the fonts, its working everywhere inthe site but it seems like convertapi is not loading them

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Graphik';
src: url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.eot');
src: url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.svg#Graphik-BlackItalic') format('svg');
font-weight: 900;
font-style: italic;
}
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

**In case anyone runs into this issue I solved by wraping the @font-face in the document head**

```
<style>
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Graphik';
  src: url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/Graphik-BlackItalic.svg#Graphik-BlackItalic')       format('svg');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: italic;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you provide your site url to test?

Comment: Could you please add ConversionDelay=10 parameter and see if it helps?

Comment: Sorry i didnt reply sooner, I solved the issue by loading the font as a style in the document head, adding a delay didnt solve my issue